# How to speedup clone speed on mercurial servers in distributed environment?

Tags: mercurial, http-proxy

I would like to know which approach would be better for using mercurial.

Currently I do have I do have 4-5 geographic sites where I have build farms and currently we are synchronizing mercurial repositories to local mercurial read-only servers in order to minimize the traffic between sites.

Still, we have lots of troubles due to failure to sync.

I am wondering if other solutions would not be better and much easier to maintain: like using HTTP proxies and eventually making the proxies invisible by using geographic DNS.

Now the build machines are using `hg clone` and the repositories are changed often.

What would be best approach to deal with this?

Note: If you have bad experience add them as comments.

Comment: I think you need to make your question more concrete. Exactly what failures are you seeing during "sync"? What does "sync" mean, do you `hg pull` or `hg push` or copy the data some other way? Finally, people shouldn't add examples of bad experiences as answers — StackOverflow isn't for discussions. Writing a mail to mercurial@selenic.com would probably be better.

Comment: I updated the question. Regarding causes for failure, these are quite complex as our setup, with branches with tens of repositories inside, hooks, ... I think we have over 1000 repositories. Now, the question is if an HTTP proxy can provide the desired speedup or not.

Comment: If you want to know if you can cache `hgweb` responses, then I think you should ask that :) (I don't know the answer to this off the top of my head.)

Comment: "failure to sync" is not clear at all